# Parameter from query not being passed into the url

Tags: php, html

I have this button which takes the first parameter of a row into a table and sends it through the url to another page. 
**Here's the code:**

```
<?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a value="edit" href="Page1.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>">Add</a></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field1"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field2"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field3"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field4"]); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

I have this code in another page, written out the same and it works perfectly, so I'm wondering what the issue here could be.

The first field I have in my table is the one I want to send through the url. It's already showing in my table so the data is existing, everything works fine.

The url ends like this:      **Page1.php?** and it's a blank page.
**If I manually put the first field of the table into the url the page shows up with the data I want.**

Here's the code of the page that sends Field1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon/elenco.png" sizes="32x32">
        
        <script  src="../../highlight.js"></script>
    </head>
<?php

    try  {
        
        require "../../../security/config.php";
        require "../../../security/common.php";

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $sql = "SELECT [...]
                FROM [...]
                ORDER BY [...]";

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
?>

<body>

<?php  
    if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    
    <header class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-12"> 
      <h1>List</h1>
    </header>
    
    <h1><br></h1>
    <a href="home.php" align='center'>Return Home.</a>
    <h1><br></h1>
    
        <table id="display-table" class="my_table" border='1' align='center'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Field 1</th>
                    <th>Field 2</th>
                    <th>Field 3</th>
                    <th>Field 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="page1.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>">Add</a></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field1"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field2"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field3"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["Field4"]); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class = "container">
    <div class = "center">
        <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?> 
<br>

</div>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvCZs.jpg    
The first column with 'Aggiungi' is the add button in the code, it sends the data of the row to the other page and fills the form with it. I can't make you see the other page as it's blank, but it's just a form that sends data through email.

Here's the code of the other page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon/elenco.png" sizes="32x32">
    </head>
<?php

    try  {
        
        require "../../../security/config.php";
        require "../../../security/common.php";

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        $name = $_GET['Field1'];
        
        $sql = "SELECT [...]
                FROM [...]
                WHERE [...];

            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
?>

<body>

<?php  
    if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
    
    <body class="w3-light-grey">

    <header class="w3-container w3-center w3-padding-12"> 
      <h1>Add</h1>
    </header>
    
    <p><br></p>
    <a href="home.php" align='center'>Return Home</a>
    
<div class = "container8">
<div class = "center">

    <form name="Form1" method="post" action="">

    <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>

        <label for="Field1">Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" id="Field1" name="Field1" value="<?php echo escape($row["Field1"]); ?>">

        <label for="Field2">Field 2</label>
            <select id="Field2" name="Field2" >
                <option value="Field11">Field11</option>
                <option value="Field12">Field12</option>
                <option value="Field13">Field13</option>
                <option value="Field14">Field14</option>
            </select>
            
        <label for="Field3">Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="Field3" id="Field3" value="<?php echo escape($row["Field3"]); ?>"> 
            
        <label for="Field4">Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="Field4" id="Field4">
            
        <label for="Field5">Field 5</label>
            <input type="text" name="Field5" id="Field5" value="<?php echo escape($row["Field5"]); ?>">
            
        <label for="Field6">Field 6</label>
            <input type="text" name="Field6" id="Field6" value="<?php echo escape($row["Field6"]); ?>">

        <label for="Field7">Field 7</label>
            <input type="date" name="Field7" id="Field7" value="<?php echo escape($row["Field7"]); ?>">

        <label for="Field8">Field 8</label>
            <input type="date" id="Field8" name="Field8">

        <label for="Field9">Field 9</label>
            <input type="text" name="Field9" id="Field9">

        <br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return OnButton1();"> 
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Appointment" onclick="return OnButton2();">

        <br><br>
    </form>

  <?php } ?>

</div>
</div>

    <?php } else { ?>
    <div class = "container">
    <div class = "center">
        <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
    </div>
    <?php } ?> 
<br>
    
</div>

</body>

</body>
</html>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "add.php"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "contact/index.php"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

This is the source code given by the browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../../favicon/elenco.png" sizes="32x32">
    </head>

<body>

    <div class = "container">
    <div class = "center">
        <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
    </div>
     
<br>
    
</div>

</body>

</body>
</html>

<script language="Javascript">
<!--
function OnButton1()
{
    document.Form1.action = "aggiungi.php"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}

function OnButton2()
{
    document.Form1.action = "contact/index.php"
    document.Form1.submit();             // Submit the page
    return true;
}
-->
</script>
```

**The whole method I'm using worked using another table.**

Comment: What _do_ you get, what does the generated HTML code look like? Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? If not, please go and do that first of all.

Comment: @CBroe I have php error reporting enabled, and what I get is a blank page with the url missing the field I'm passing on it.

Comment: So what exactly does the generated HTML source code look like for that part of the page then? (_Actual_ source code view in browser, _not_ DOM inspector.)

Comment: Btw: `<a value="edit"` - links do not have a `value` attribute.

Comment: That page takes the first field with $_GET, uses it in a query to fill out a form

Comment: Don’t know what that is supposed to tell us now. Answer the actual question I asked you for clarification, please.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you are asking me to show

Comment: I am asking you to _verify_ what the actual HTML code this script created, looks like. Your browser should have a context menu option “show page source” or similar for that.

Comment: I've clicked that and it shows me the page I'm linking on the table

Comment: Please _show us_, what the HTML code that `<td><a value="edit" href="Page1.php?Field1=<?php echo $row['Field1'];?>">Add</a></td>` generated, actually looks like.

Comment: @CBroe I've added the two pages

Comment: You are still showing us the PHP code, which is NOT what I asked you for! None of us here have your complete setup including the database available, so none of us here will be able to tell what _output_ this script actually produces - only you can do that. But for some reason you are refusing to, despite having been told several times by now, _what_ you should please show us.

Comment: @CBroe I've added an image where you can see what it's displayed. The second page is just a form filled with data sent from the first page.

Comment: That is not the HTML **CODE**, but the rendered result.

Comment: I've uploaded every single line of code, the whole 2 pages are up here.

Comment: That is still your PHP code. I asked you to show us what the HTML this created, looked like.

Comment: The html is implemented with the php, there's literally nothing else I could show.

Comment: Yes, there is - the actual HTML code this PHP code will _create_. As I also already told you: _‘Your browser should have a context menu option “show page source” or similar for that.’_

Comment: [How to view the HTML source code of a web page](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm)

Comment: @CBroe I've added what it shows me

Comment: First and foremost, I meant the result of the first PHP code you have shown us - that, where you are actually _creating_ the links inside the table, that you said are not working properly. If you say those link to `Page1.php?` only, then the first thing to check would be if those actually got generated correctly.

Comment: @CBroe how can I check if those got generated correctly? The strange thing is that this whole method works using another table.

Comment: @CBroe like, I took the old page and put the new table parameters into it and it doesn't pass the parameter into the url to the other page

Answer (score 0):

i have checked out your code, you need to check your SQL Query and SQL result
and specifically check `$row["Field1"]` that contain any value or not.

**how you can perform the check ?**

1. just simply `echo $row["Field1"];`
   if the output would be blank that means it doesn't contain any value
2. another method is using `var_dump($row["Field1"]);`
   it will give you some detailed information

**How did i figured out ? and you can also give it a try**

just set the `$row["Field1"] = 1;` explicitly

and the try to run your code again, if that worked this time , then there is something error with SQL side

Comment: I know that $row["Field1"] contains a value because its value is displayed on the table.

Comment: Also I added a column with var_dump($row["Field1"]); and it works perfectly displaying me data